# How to give ownership inside Rust future

Tags: rust, future, lifetime

I have a chain of Rust futures which needs to take ownership of a variable outside of the future, however, I don't understand how I can pass the ownership of the variable into one of the chains.

The issue seems to be on the 'address' variable being used by 'let domain = DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str(&address).unwrap()', as replacing &address with a string will make it work.

I have looked up putting the variable into a Arc/Mutex and Rc/RefCell, but they don't seem to help (maybe I'm just doing it wrong). I feel like I understand that I need to basically give ownership of all the variable to future closures, since they are going to outlive the current function, but I don't have a clue how to do that...

```
let address = inner.address().unwrap();

state.check_net(&address)?;

let op = resolve_addr(&address)
    .and_then(move |socket_address| {
      TcpStream::connect(&socket_address)
        .map_err(ErrBox::from)
    })
    .and_then(move |socket| {
      let mut config = ClientConfig::new();
      config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
      let config = TlsConnector::from(Arc::new(config));
      let domain = DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str(&address).unwrap();
      config.connect(domain, socket)
        .map_err(ErrBox::from)
    })
    .and_then(move |tls_stream| new_tls_conn(cmd_id, tls_stream));
  if base.sync() {
    let buf = op.wait()?;
    Ok(Op::Sync(buf))
  } else {
    Ok(Op::Async(Box::new(op)))
  }
```

And the error I get:

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `base`
    --> ../../cli/ops.rs:1748:18
     |
1716 |   base: &msg::Base<'_>,
     |         -------------- help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `base`: `&msg::Base<'static>`
...
1748 |     Ok(Op::Async(Box::new(op)))
     |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have gotten it to work by basically cloning the `address` variable with `address.to_owned()` like so:

```
let address = inner.address().unwrap();
let domain = address.to_owned();

state.check_net(&address)?;

let op = resolve_addr(&address)
    .and_then(move |socket_address| {
      TcpStream::connect(&socket_address)
        .map_err(ErrBox::from)
    })
    .and_then(move |socket| {
      let mut config = ClientConfig::new();
      config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
      let config = TlsConnector::from(Arc::new(config));
      let domain = DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str(&domain).unwrap();
      config.connect(domain, socket)
        .map_err(ErrBox::from)
    })
    .and_then(move |tls_stream| new_tls_conn(cmd_id, tls_stream));
if base.sync() {
    let buf = op.wait()?;
    Ok(Op::Sync(buf))
} else {
    Ok(Op::Async(Box::new(op)))
}
```

I'm not too sure why this works though. If anyone could explain that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Futures (as of version 0.1) don't work well with borrowed data for exactly the reason you ran into here. Any references inside a future have to be static because the lifetime of a borrow inside a future can't be tracked by the compiler statically. This is one of the major motivations of the upcoming async/await syntax, and in particular the concept of "pinning" which enables borrows that can live across await points. Until async/await is stable, the easiest workaround is to do what you have done: make sure futures own their data by copying/cloning.

Comment: So by using address.to_owned(), I am copying the string, however I don't quite understand why this would mean the Future can all of a sudden 'own' the data.

Is it because address is used once in resolve_address(), and therefore that future now 'owns' it, and then using it again in the chain is throwing it off?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what the type of the local variable `address` is, but assuming it's a reference, calling `to_owned` on it will give you an owned version of the same data, usually by copying/cloning it. When you use `address` inside a closure annotated with `move`, the value gets moved from the containing scope to the closure itself. However, if `address` is itself a reference, then the closure contains borrowed data, which the borrow checker can't deal with in stable Rust as of today.

Comment: It may also help to understand that closures are "desugared" by the compiler into a struct that contains all the values that it captures from its environment. So in this case, you had something like `struct Closure123<'a> { address: &'a Thing, ... }` which is what the borrow checker has trouble with in async code. By converting `address` to an owned value, the closure instead desugars to `struct Closure123 { address: Thing, ... }` which the borrow checker has no problem with.